# Multiple mysql database usage and management in php

Tags: php, mysql

My script requires connections to several databases. Some parts only need to connect to one, which is all fine and dandy, however in some cases I need to perform queries on different database in a single script execution.

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
function db_connect($which) {
    if($which == "main") {
        $maindb = mysqli_connect(HOSTNAME_1, USER, PASSWORD, MAIN_DB);
        return $maindb;
    } elseif($which == "stats") {
        $statsdb = mysqli_connect(HOSTNAME_2, USER, PASSWORD, STATS_DB);
        return $statsdb;
    }
}


$maindb = db_connect("main");
$statsdb = db_connect("stats");
```

I maintain the actual hostname, username, password and db name in a config file full of constants.

I then use the respective links on different queries.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: You could store your databaseconfigs in arrays and do `mysqli_connect($config[$db]['hostname'],$config[$db]['user',...)`.  That's how codeigniter does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite good, although you shoul try not to duplicate your code :

```
function db_connect($which) {
    if($which == "main") {
        $host = HOSTNAME_1;
        $db = MAIN_DB;
    } elseif($which == "stats") {
        $host = HOSTNAME_2;
        $db = STATS_DB;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('unknown db');
    }
    return mysqli_connect($host, USER, PASSWORD, $db);
}


$maindb = db_connect("main");
$statsdb = db_connect("stats");
```

Comment: You will get an error now if $which is something else than main or stats and you should also modify the selection of the database (MAIN_DB and STATS_DB).

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be ok. An alternative would be to use the class mysqli instead of the functions in order to manipulate objects instead of identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your databaseconfigs in arrays and use that. That's how codeigniter does it.

```
function get_database_config(){
    $config['main']['hostname'] = "host1";
    $config['main']['user']     = "user1";
    $config['main']['password'] = "pass1";
    $config['main']['database'] = "database1";

    $config['stats']['hostname'] = "host2";
    $config['stats']['user']     = "user2";
    $config['stats']['password'] = "pass2";
    $config['stats']['database'] = "database2";

    return $config;
}

function db_connect($db)
{
    $config = get_database_config();
    return mysqli_connect( 
            $config[$db]['hostname'],
            $config[$db]['user'],
            $config[$db]['password'],
            $config[$db]['database']
    );
}
```

If you don't want to work with an associative array and prefer to work with constants, you could name your constants as `MAIN_HOSTNAME, STATS_HOSTNAME, ...` and use `constant($which . '_HOSTNAME')` as input for mysqli_connect().